# Two dimensional ReadOnlyObservableCollection

Tags: c#, collections, observablecollection

I want to bind `Foo.Data` property and I need it to be two dimensional `ObservableCollection`. Since I don't want `Data` property to be changed outside of the `Foo` class I'm trying to expose it as `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`. But updating the encapsulated `_data` field don't update the `Data` property.

```
public sealed class Foo
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> _data;

    public Foo()
    {
        _data = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>();

        // this line gives compile time error
        // cannot convert from ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> to ObservableCollection<ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>>
        // Data = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>>(_data);

        // Fill the _data variable
        for (var i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            var t = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            for (var j = 0; j<10; j++)
            {
                t.Add(i + "+" + j);
            }
            _data.Add(t);
        }

        var tmp = new ObservableCollection<ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>>();
        foreach (var row in _data)
        {
            tmp.Add(new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(row));
        }
        Data = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>>(tmp);
    }

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>> Data { get; }

    public void RemoveItem(int x, int y)
    {
        _data[x].RemoveAt(y); // This does update the Data collection.
    }

    public void RemoveRow(int x)
    {
        _data.RemoveAt(x); // This does not update the Data collection.
    }
}
```

Here is a [working sample](http://ideone.com/M3RYcP).

FYI: If you want to edit or rerun the code, just click on fork.

I've searched the web about it but I couldn't find anything. Is not two dimensional `ObservableCollection`s a thing, is there a better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RemoveRow` method does not update the `Data` collection because `_data` is not related to `Data` (except that they share some content). The collection related to `Data` is `tmp`, so I would try the following:

- Make `tmp` class member and give it a name (e.g. `_rowData`)
- rename `_data` to `_itemData`
- use `_rowData` in `RemoveRow`

This is the result:

```
public sealed class Foo
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> _itemData;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>> _rowData;

    public Foo()
    {
        _itemData = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>();

        // Fill the _itemData variable
        for (var i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            var t = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            for (var j = 0; j<10; j++)
            {
                t.Add(i + "+" + j);
            }
            _itemData .Add(t);
        }

        _rowData = new ObservableCollection<ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>>();
        foreach (var row in _itemData )
        {
            _rowData.Add(new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(row));
        }
        Data = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>>(_rowData);
    }

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>> Data { get; }

    public void RemoveItem(int x, int y)
    {
        _itemData[x].RemoveAt(y);
    }

    public void RemoveRow(int x)
    {
        _rowData.RemoveAt(x);
    }
}
```